# JDeveloper DB-based MDS-connection issue

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

During creating of DB-based MDS-connection in JDeveloper list of partitions is empty.
I have tried to install Oracle SOA Suite 11g on both Oracle and SQL Server and have this issue in JDeveloper with different jdbc-drivers.
Of course, MDS schemas in database are created using Oracle Repository Creation utility and both sys/sa and DEV_MDS users were tried.

I have looked into JDeveloper Messages tab and see such error:

WARNING: Error reading db partitions for connection name Connection1. Reason : MDS-00003: error connecting to the database
Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager MBean: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Universal Connection Pool configuration: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create factory class instance with provided factory class name: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager MBean: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Universal Connection Pool configuration: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create factory class instance with provided factory class name: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource

It is strange, because it is class from sqljdbc4.jar which I have specified as JDBC-driver (Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0).

So I tried jTDS SQL Server driver and received such error:

Apr 26, 2011 9:52:01 PM oracle.tip.tools.ide.common.resourcepalette.adapter.mds.DBConnectionInfo
WARNING: Error reading db partitions for connection name Connection2. Reason :

Answer (score 4):

This answer is coming a "bit" late, but hopefully it will be of some use to the next coder who stumbles upon this.

I'm currently banging my head to the wall trying to get a simple SOA/BPM/ADF application built and deployed using MS SQL Server as the backend DB containing the MDS data.

I was able to create a DB connection to the SQL Server instance with JDeveloper, but I ran into the same problem as Denys when I tried to create a new MDS Connection: The list of partitions was empty and after several hours (or days) I discovered the same error message in the Messages tab:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
```

even though the actual DB connection was working properly.

Also, whenever I tried to build my application using JDeveloper's build command or Maven or Ant tasks, I received the same error.

All of the errors pointed in the direction of a missing JDBC driver, which was actually not missing.

I was finally able to at least partially solve the issue, although I had to use very dirty hacks.

**Solution to create MDS connection in JDeveloper:**

To get this to work I had to make the MDS module realize that there actually exists a JDBC driver for SQL server, so I added the driver's jar into the module's classpath in `${jdev.home}/extensions/oracle.mds.dt.jar#META-INF/extension.xml`:

```
<classpath>c:/dev/jdbc/mssql/sqljdbc4.jar</classpath>
```

In my opinion, it should have been enough to just have the driver in the project's library settings, but somehow that just wouldn't cut it.

**Solution to get the ant scac task working:**

I got the build a bit forward by doing essentially the same thing. I added the JDBC driver's jar into scac's classpath by modifying `${jdev.home}/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml`:

```
<path id="scac.tasks.class.path">
    <!-- Added this line -->
    <pathelement path="c:/dev/jdbc/mssql/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
</path>
```

All in all, these are not the kind of solutions I was hoping for, but maybe someone else will benefit from them.

Now I'm at the point where my composite.xml validation fails because of missing and/or broken wsdl files:

```
[scac] Validating composite "C:\install\fod\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\bin/..//composite.xml"
[scac] error: location {/ns:composite/ns:import[@location='oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl']}(15,125): Load of wsdl "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl" failed
[scac] error: location {/ns:composite/ns:import[@location='oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/partnersupplier/PartnerSupplierComposite.wsdl']}(25,30): Load of wsdl "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/partnersupplier/PartnerSupplierComposite.wsdl" failed
[scac] error: location {/ns:composite/ns:import[@location='oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl']}(29,30): Load of wsdl "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl" failed
... continues with errors for everything else
```

This error occurs when trying to execute the compile-build-all task in Oracle's Fusion Order Demo application. Any advice regarding this is most welcome.